# JPA does not fill one column of another entity

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, null, nativequery

I have created a JPA query to obtain a set of data. What it returns is an entity and a new field (an extra column) in each of the records.

```
@Query(value = "C.id_transaccion as transacionId, SELECT A.* FROM (modulos A RIGHT JOIN modulos2 B ON A.uu_id_modulo = B.uu_id_modulo) LEFT JOIN operacion C ON B.id_operacion = C.uu_id_operacion WHERE uu_id = ( :uudId)", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Module> queryModules(@Param("uu_id") Integer uuId);
```

Which through `JPA` my object is filled correctly but, the extra field '`transacionId`' always returns `null`. Why? I have tried if it was a problem of the name that I have given it but it is not.

My `Entity`:

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
public class Module {
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer uuIdModule;

    private Integer transacionId;
}
```

Is the problem that `transacionId` is not a column? Then, does not belong to 'Module' entity, and it is not able to map it?

Comment: No, problem is: it is part of the mapping, but the column is assumed in your table, thus null. You have to look at "JPA projections"

Comment: This content might help you: https://thorben-janssen.com/spring-data-jpa-dto-native-queries/

Comment: @xerx593 thank you so much, it helps me. You can post the link and some helpful answer and i will check it with correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I used JPA-Projections to resolve it. Its an interface with the attributes name prefixed by 'get'.

```
public interface ModuleProjection {
    
    Integer getTransactionId();
}
```